# How can I make my Symfony2 form input fields look like the ones in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony, twig

I'm trying to integrate Twitter Bootstrap into Symfony2. I've already added the links to CSS and JS Bootstrap files on the top of my Twig form template **form1.twig.html**

```
<link href="{{ asset('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="{{ asset('bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
```

I've checked that the links are correct, but, anyway, my form input fields are not getting the Bootstrap style.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you added the class to your html elements ? Can you share your Html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to make use of Form Themes

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#form-theming-in-twig

For example, you can override the default form_row widget

```
{% block form_row %}
    {% spaceless %}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form_label(form) }}
            {{ form_widget(form, { 'attr' : { 'class' : 'form-control' } }) }}
            {{ form_errors(form) }}
        </div>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_row %}
```

Then in your twig template file with the form, apply the theme to the form object:

```
{% form_theme form "SomeBundle:Form:bootstrap_form_row.html.twig" %}

{{ form_row(form.field) }}
```